# how can make the Periods ring next to scientist (no space)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
variable1 = "I"
variable2 = "plan"
variable3= "to"
variable4= "think"
variable5="like"
variable6= "a"
variable7="computer"
variable8= "scientist"
variable9= "."
print(variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5,variable6,variable7,variable8,variable9)
```

i got

```
I plan to think like a computer scientist .
```

i hope to get

```
I plan to think like a computer scientist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `print()` calls, one to print the first 8 words separated by spaces, then another to print the `.`. Use `end=''` in the first call so it won't go to a new line after it.

```
print(variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5,variable6,variable7,variable8, end='')
print(variable9)
```

Answer (score 0):

There're tons of ways to do this. One simple and adhoc way is

```
' '.join(['I', 'plan', 'to', 'think', 'like', 'a', 'computer', 'scientist', '.']).replace(' .', '.')
```